# Как добавить файл HTML в конкретный блок (div) с использованием PHP?

Tags: php, html

У меня есть этот код PHP, который отображает файл HTML.

```
<?php
include("pages/home.html");
// ...
?>
```

Мне нужно в блок с идентификатором `#header` из отображённой страницы включить ещё один HTML. Как это сделать?

**То есть чтобы это выглядело примерно так**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Main Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">Другой HTML здесь.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: воспользуйтесь функциями буферизации вывода https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php. Таким образом получите текст из файл home.html в переменной. А дальше проделывайте любые манипуляции любым удобным способом.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за совет! Приемлимо ли потом идти путем использования инструмента DomDocument?

Comment: На самом деле - нет. У вас что-то не так с архитектурой приложения, раз вам пришлось использовать `ob_start` для изменения значений в html. Правильным подходом должно быть использование шаблонизаторов.

Comment: Но я не хочу использовать чужое ПО. Можете посоветовать, как поступить лучше по другому?

Comment: Это не совсем правильный подход. Вы можете не использовать готовые библиотеки, но вам придётся написать их аналоги самостоятельно. При этом вы не учтёте кучу нюансов, которые в этих библиотеках уже учтены. При этом вы потратите кучу времени на переписывание своего кода, чтобы он сохранял архитектурность и при этом обеспечивал требуемую функциональность. Это своего рода обучение через наступание на собственные грабли. Профессионал же учится на граблях чужих. К этому нужно стремиться.

Answer (score -1):

создайте 3 файла
header.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>The Main Page</title>
```

body.php

```
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">Другой HTML здесь.</div>
```

footer.php

```
</body>
<footer>
```

в index.php поместите следующее:

```
<?php
include("header.php");
include("body.php");
include("footer.php");
?>
```

между ними можете выводить нужные вам элементы, но такая структура документа больше подходит для обучения, когда углубите знания выберите более удачную модель